# Basic Python Regular expression: re.DOTALL *not* matching new lines

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I want to turn all occurrences of A...A into B...B for some filler between the two A's.  The filler must be allowed to contain new line characters. I assumed `re.DOTALL` was the solution.

Here's a python script:

```
import re

tt1 = re.sub(r'A(?P<text>.*)A','B\g<text>B','AhiA')
print tt1 
tt1 = re.sub(r'A(?P<text>.*)A','B\g<text>B','A\nhiA')
print tt1 
tt1 = re.sub(r'A(?P<text>[.]*)A','B\g<text>B','A\nhiA')
print tt1 
tt1 = re.sub(r'A(?P<text>.*)A','B\g<text>B','A\nhiA',re.DOTALL)
print tt1
```

And here's the output:

```
BhiB
A
hiA
A
hiA
A
hiA
```

What gives, and how can I replace 'A\nhiA' with 'B\nhiB'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fourth parameter to [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is `count` (the maximum number of replace operations to be performed). `re.DOTALL` is `16`, so you're passing a (valid) parameter in an unexpected place.

Use

```
re.sub(r'A(?P<text>.*)A','B\g<text>B','A\nhiA', flags=re.DOTALL)
```

(or place `re.DOTALL` in position five):

```
re.sub(r'A(?P<text>.*)A','B\g<text>B','A\nhiA', 0, re.DOTALL)
```